# Xamarin Android cannot override OnBackButtonPressed method

Tags: xamarin.android, onbackpressed

My problem is whenever i try to override OnBackButtonPressed visual studio just tells me that there are no method that can be override.
Here is the code

```
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults){
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

whenever i remove "override" tag the error disapper but the evente is never triggered.
Any idea why cant override this method?

Comment: `OnBackButtonPressed` is a NavigationPage method, meaning it can only be overrided in the view code-behind, i think what you are looking for is `OnBackPressed`

Answer (score 1):

OnBackPressed is an Android method, you can override it in the file MainActivity.cs this way:

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    // your code over here
    base.OnBackPressed();
}
```